# Docker containers can't communicate on the outside network

Tags: linux, centos, docker, vmware

We have a Docker host (A virtual machine) hosted on VMware. This docker host has two network interfaces. ens160 and ens192

- ens192 is configured with a normal IP address
- ens160 is configured without an IP address with promiscuous mode ON
- Promiscuous mode is also ON in the Port Group in vmware
- IP forwarding is enabled : `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- firewalld on the Dockerhost is off

#### Interfaces

```
[root@dockerone ~]# netstat -i
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
docker0   1500      393      0      0 0          1405      0      0      0 BMRU
ens160    1500 16034090      0     89 0          1255      0      0      0 BMPRU
ens192    1500    96324      0      1 0          6352      0      0      0 BMRU
ens160.2  1500    97658      0      0 0           362      0      0      0 BMPRU
```

#### Network Creation

```
docker network  create  -d macvlan --subnet=10.200.131.0/24 --gateway=10.200.131.1 -o parent=ens160.231 macvlan231
```

#### Container creation

```
docker run --name alp1 --net=macvlan231 --ip=10.200.131.191 -itd alpine /bin/sh
docker exec -it alp1 sh

docker run --name alp2  --net=macvlan231 --ip=10.200.131.190 -itd alpine /bin/sh
docker exec -it alp2 sh
```

The two containers can communicate with one another but not to the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh figured it out...
On the VMware virtual switch port group, all three need to be enabled:
1. Promiscous Mode
2. MAC Address Changes
3. Forged transmits